# Can't deploy MEAN stack app to Azure App Service via pipeline

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm unable to deploy my app to azure app service. I've created a pipeline that fails at the azure app service deploy stage. I've been trying to get this working for a few days now. I've finally gotten it past the deploy app stage, but it just says Application Error when I click URL? and I configure it to point to the correct subscription. Web App for Linux, then chose the app-service call gc-dev, but I get errors still. I also get the same application error when trying to deploy app from vscode. It's possible both deployment types are dealing with exact same issue. IDK though.

I feel like it has something to do with the startup command since nothing is calling ng serve to launch angular code, but I'm not sure. Another thing that might be relevant to the issue is that all my angular services still have `http://localhost:3000/api/` instead of some cloud url. Not sure if that's the issue with the inital page load though. I feel like it should still at least load the login screen. I appreciate any help!

Deploy Stage

[image]

The steps are as follows:

```
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'install the @anguliar/cli'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: glass/
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install @angular/cli -g'


steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'install the project'
  inputs:
    workingDir: glass/
    verbose: false

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'build project'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: my-app/
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install the dist/folder for express'
  inputs:
    workingDir: my-app/dist/
    verbose: false
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Build the project'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: my-app
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'


steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: my-app dev'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure subscription 1 (99c421dc-5cf5-444c-8df5-c71[![enter image description here][2]][2]02)'
    appType: webAppLinux
    WebAppName: 'gc-dev'
    packageForLinux: my-app
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile index.js -appType node'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: false
```

Comment: Where did you host Anguler front end ?

Comment: Maybe that's where I'm confused. Do I deploy them separately? I thought it would hand deploying both at the same time. Also I tried separately if that is the case. I pointed it to dist\\main and it wouldn't even bring up the main html page. It should atleast do that. I know I wouldn't be able to login without backend, but I should see something I would think

Comment: you can follow this https://medium.com/ngconf/angular-on-azure-part-i-d842e8f76462

Comment: I looked at the tutorial, but it only covers angular. I need help deploying with my express/nodejs server too. I updated my question too.

Comment: the `npm install`step doesnt look correct... are you sure all steps are passing... do you have error log from azure portal

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, this cannot be correct:

```
WebAppName: 'My-app - Dev'
```

You can't have spaces in App Service app names. It's part of the default URL.

Comment: I created a new app service called ```gc-dev``` see images for reference. When I run the pipeline, I get farther now, but then I get a different error on the Azure App Service Deploy task  that says 

```ng build 
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/glass/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
``` 
Not sure why, but it did get past the other build project task. It takes like 7 mins on that task before failing.

updated App Service name: https://postimg.cc/5jr1h3rB  
app service: https://postimg.cc/3466cLwW